# Element-wise "OR" operation on vectors in C++

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to use an or (|) operator on vectors in C++. After hours of research, I can not find any functions that work directly on vectors, therefore I am currently writing something like this:

```
int len = 10; 
std::vector<bool> v1(len);
std::vector<bool> v2(len);
std::vector<bool> vout(len);

//Some code to determine the content of v1 and v2

for(int i = 0; i < len ; i++)
{
   vout[i] = v1[i] | v2[i];
}
```

However, I think that this slows down my code, and therefore I am wondering if there are any methods of taking the or-operator on two vectors?

Comment: using bitwise OR (aka: |) on bool types is meaningless, you should use boolean OR (aka ||)

Comment: something like vout = v1 || v2; ? That does not compile for me..

Comment: Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset . This is a sequence of bits, on which you can use bitwise logic.

Comment: *"I think that this slows down my code*" based on what exactly? You didn't show any benchmark. You also didn't mention _how_ exactly this might slow down anything.

Comment: I did not have anything to benchmark it against since I did not know any other alternatives. As you can see from my comments on the two good answers below, my assumption was probably wrong since the two answers did not speed up my code as much as I would have thought. 

In that way, I was probably wrong, but nonetheless, I found simpler ways of writing the code I was looking to speed up.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `std::transform`:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/

```cpp
// transform algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::transform
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <functional>   // std::plus

int op_increase (int i) { return ++i; }

int main () {
  std::vector<int> foo;
  std::vector<int> bar;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
    foo.push_back (i*10);                         // foo: 10 20 30 40 50

  bar.resize(foo.size());                         // allocate space

  std::transform (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), op_increase);
                                                  // bar: 11 21 31 41 51

  // std::plus adds together its two arguments:
  std::transform (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), foo.begin(), std::plus<int>());
                                                  // foo: 21 41 61 81 101

  std::cout << "foo contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=foo.begin(); it!=foo.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seemed to work very well. Thank you! It did not seem to speed up the code so much, but it was a much nicer way of programming it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<bool> v1 = { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
    std::vector<bool> v2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    std::vector<bool> v3;
    v3.reserve( v1.size() );

    std::transform( v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 
        std::back_inserter( v3 ), std::logical_or<>() );

    for ( auto item : v1 ) std::cout << std::boolalpha<< item << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "OR\n";
    for ( auto item : v1 ) std::cout << std::boolalpha<< item << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "=\n";
    for ( auto item : v3 ) std::cout << std::boolalpha<< item << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true false true true false false 
OR
true false true true false false 
=
true false true true false true
```

That is you can use the standard algorithm `std::transform` and the functional object `std::logical_or`.

Comment: Yes, it seems like std::transform is the algorithm for this task. Your answer was somewhat slower than the answer of RBreuer in my code, but thanks for showing this std::logical_or which was great.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the | operator like that:

```
std::vector<bool> operator |(std::vector<bool> v1,std::vector<bool> v2)
{
    std::vector<bool> result(len);
    for(int i = 0; i < len ; i++)
         result[i] = v1[i] | v2[i];
    return result;
}
```

And in main you call

```
std::vctor<bool> result(len) = v1 | v2;
```